# Best possible way to answer c++

Tags: c++

Hi am given a array table and a question. The three highest data and their corresponding sector quarters and years. How am i suppose to do this the correct and best way using c++?

```
int Man[] = { 18080,18961,18985,18761,17821,19021,18452,20000 };
int Infra[] = { 4922,4904,4993,5076,4970,4900,4718,4757 };
int Ser[] = { 13898,14424,14290,14362,12623,13139,13775,15081 };
int Trans[] = { 7382,7323,7304,7675,7147,7335,6972,7740 };
int Others[] = { 1398,1438,1414,1435,1361,1420,1450,1476 };
```

The array quarter being the number of arrays and 2 years 2015 and 2016.... split between array 0-3 and 4-7

I hope you all can understand,sorry if my terms for c++ is bad. Thank you

Comment: The three highest data?. The simplest would probably be [to use `std::sort` to sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) descending and then present the three first numbers in the array. Good programming style recommends that you start with the simplest solution that can work and work your way up in complexity as solutions fail to meet other constrains such as performance..

Comment: Even if your english is poor, please don't use "chatspeak".  Spell out words - like "you" instead of "u"

Answer (score 0):

You could start writing a maximum function like:

```
int easy_max(int[] array, int from, int to) {
    if (from < to){ //2 or more elements
       //divide
        int max_index_1 = easy_max(array, from, from + (from-to)/2); 
        int max_index_2 = easy_max(array, from + (from-to)/2 + 1, to); 

        if(max_index_1 == -1 || max_index_2 == -1)
            return -1; //Forward the error if there is one

        //conquer
        if(array[max_index_1] > array[max_index_2])
            return max_index_1;
        else
            return max_index_2;
    }
    if (from == to) return from; //Recursion anchor
    else if (from > to) return -1; //Invalid Input
}
```

So you can evaluate the maximum of every array. Be aware that you here have to pay attention to only access existing array space.

If you have understood this, you can try to get into lists a bit to get the top n elements. Usually, you would probably order the lists (but don't forget your indices: the respecting quarter years... which belongs to which). For this, there are [sophisticated standard functions like this](https://%20http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/sort/).